# Authentication failed in the front end (Angular/Spring)

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security

My front end code is based on this link http://embed.plnkr.co/toe4XO/, except for the `authentication/service.js` file, I change the code into following:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Authentication')

.factory('AuthenticationService',
    ['Base64', '$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout',
    function (Base64, $http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout) {
        var service = {};

        service.Login = function (username, password, callback) {

            /* Dummy authentication for testing, uses $timeout to simulate api call
             ----------------------------------------------*/
            //$timeout(function(){
            //    var response = { success: username === 'test' && password === 'test' };
            //    if(!response.success) {
            //        response.message = 'Username or password is incorrect';
            //    }
            //    callback(response);
            //}, 1000);


            /* Use this for real authentication
             ----------------------------------------------*/
            $http.post('http://localhost:8080/AngularSpringBackend/authenticate', { username: username, password: password })
                .success(function (response) {
                    callback(response);
                });

        };

        service.SetCredentials = function (username, password) {
            var authdata = Base64.encode(username + ':' + password);

            $rootScope.globals = {
                currentUser: {
                    username: username,
                    authdata: authdata
                }
            };

            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + authdata; // jshint ignore:line
            $cookieStore.put('globals', $rootScope.globals);
        };

        service.ClearCredentials = function () {
            $rootScope.globals = {};
            $cookieStore.remove('globals');
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ';
        };

        return service;
    }])

.factory('Base64', function () {
    /* jshint ignore:start */

    var keyStr = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';

    return {
        encode: function (input) {
            var output = "";
            var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
            var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
            var i = 0;

            do {
                chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
                chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
                chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

                enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
                enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
                enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
                enc4 = chr3 & 63;

                if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                    enc3 = enc4 = 64;
                } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                    enc4 = 64;
                }

                output = output +
                    keyStr.charAt(enc1) +
                    keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
                    keyStr.charAt(enc3) +
                    keyStr.charAt(enc4);
                chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
                enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";
            } while (i < input.length);

            return output;
        },

        decode: function (input) {
            var output = "";
            var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
            var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
            var i = 0;

            // remove all characters that are not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /, or =
            var base64test = /[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g;
            if (base64test.exec(input)) {
                window.alert("There were invalid base64 characters in the input text.\n" +
                    "Valid base64 characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, '+', '/',and '='\n" +
                    "Expect errors in decoding.");
            }
            input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

            do {
                enc1 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
                enc2 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
                enc3 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
                enc4 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

                chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
                chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
                chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

                if (enc3 != 64) {
                    output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
                }
                if (enc4 != 64) {
                    output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
                }

                chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
                enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";

            } while (i < input.length);

            return output;
        }
    };

    /* jshint ignore:end */
});
```

Also all the front end code I put into IIS folder. My back end code need basic authentication to access the API, , and the url is under port 8080 in the localhost, also all the login information are already stored in the database.

My backend implementation is Spring/Hibernate, I test it using postman, and it works I want. Now if I try to click the login button from my front end page, the login page is keep looping, and console give me following error:
[Error message from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDBjW.png), what I done wrong?

The expected behavior should be when user enter the valid account, it can access the api, and also get into the home page.

Here is my backend code is in github.com/zhengye1/SpringAngular

Thank you for your help.

**Update (April 12, 2017)**
Github code are update based on the comment below. But I still didn't get what I want.

Reply for Ajit Soman's comment:
In postman, when I paste my url link, for example `http://localhost:8080/AngularSpringBackend/api/v1/users/`, then click Authorization , choose Type is Basic Auth, put in the admin/admin as username and password, it return the lists of user, which can be retrieve from database.

After I read `https://samerabdelkafi.wordpress.com/2016/01/25/secure-angularjs-application-with-spring-security/`, my understanding is in service.js, I need to change the post call into `http://localhost:8080/AngularSpringBackend/authenticate`. Now I enter `http://localhost/SimpleTest/#/login` in Chrome, enter admin/admin as username and password in the login page, hit login, spring security will handle the rest and make authentication success and route to home page, but seems like not this case, Do I misunderstand something?

**Update (April 18,2017)**
Finally get what I want, but it may have security problem. The way I do is in 'authentication/service.js', I change to 
```         service.Login = function (username, password, callback) {
              var base64Credentials = btoa(username + ':' + password);
              console.log(base64Credentials);

```
            console.log(username + ":" + password);
            /* Dummy authentication for testing, uses $timeout to simulate api call
             ----------------------------------------------*/
            //$timeout(function(){
            //    var response = { success: username === 'test' && password === 'test' };
            //    if(!response.success) {
            //        response.message = 'Username or password is incorrect';
            //    }
            //    callback(response);
            //}, 1000);


            /* Use this for real authentication
             ----------------------------------------------*/
        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/AngularSpringBackend/login?username='+username ,
            headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64Credentials,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        };
    $http(req).then(function (response) {
    callback(response);
```

In my backend, I need to add one controller class, mapped the "/login" path to the login method, using path variable to get the username, specify the method to POST and OPTIONS, and everything works.

Is any good approach to achieve the requirement I want other the method I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

In your corsFilter @Component annotation is missing. So please add @component like this

```
@Component
    public class CORSFilter implements Filter{
        static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CORSFilter.class);
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) 
                throws IOException, ServletException {
    ...
}
```

@Component indicates a auto scan component and this will let your spring container to auto scan CORSFilter.

Comment: Already add it, but still, in the server console, it gave me org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
 at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84)
 at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124)
... Maybe I still missing something?

Comment: I have searched "/api/authenticate", i found it in securityConfiguration.java what is see there ..you have commented out //.loginProcessingUrl("/api/authenticate")  also you are hitting url- http://localhost:8080/AngularSpringBackend/api/authenticate with angular. Could you explain why you did this.

Comment: So I should not comment out that line? Cuz I don't know how to approach the expected I want...  can you give me some suggestions?

Comment: Please confirm me did you able to hit your login API with postman. if so please tell me url and body data. if you are able to hit with postman then there will be no issue with hitting  URL with angularjs.